# Are the two following figures same?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Are the two figures same?

I have drawn the feedback topology for voltage shunt type. I just want to clear a doubt if these two refer to the same thing and if there is anything wrong.

I am not so confident with the first diagram.

Comment: The first diagram doesn't show how the feedback connects back to the input of the circuit. There's no actual feedback happening in that circuit at all.

Comment: The second diagram is a bit confusing to follow because you connected the positive terminals of the forward path to the negative terminals of the feedback block and vice versa.

Comment: so in the second diagram what changes should i make to make it more legible and perceivable @ThePhoton

Comment: It would help to label the terminals as positive or negative, and then make sure you're connecting the ones you want where you want.

Comment: but is the second one problematic

Comment: I believe it is correct if you want to show positive shunt-shunt feedback.

Comment: Should be positive output terminal to positive input terminal and negative output terminal to negative input terminal.

Comment: ummm but isnt it already in the figure?

Comment: I actually dont get the last comment

Comment: @pole star yeah I was just agreeing with The photon with the naming of polarity of connections.

Comment: These pictures are neither block diagrams nor circuit diagrams. You need to add your analysis so that we can see what you think is going on.